# How to make MKAnnotationView more sensitive in the MapKit?

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotation, callouts

I have a custom `MKAnnotationView` appear with a `UIImageView` by the size 16*16, and when user tap on it, I use the protocol

```
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    [mapView setCenterCoordinate:view.annotation.coordinate];
}
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [calloutView setHidden:!selected];
}
```

to pop up a customized `calloutView` . It can works OK. But sometime it may take two or three times or even more to make the  annotation sensitive and invoke the method to show the `calloutView`. Is there anyone have faced this issue and there is some solution to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved it. 
We must give the customized `MKAnnotationView` a image and the User Interaction bound is the image's `CGSize`. So I made a transparent image and assign it to the `MKAnnotationView`'s image property.

```
self.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparent36.png"];
```

it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

You should tapp at the center of the `MKAnnotationView`, and also try adding the

```
imageView.center = annotationView.center;
```

try